# Fastest way to connect Android to Arduino wirelessly?

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino, connect

I'm looking for a really quick, easy, mostly plug-and-play way to connect Android to Arduino wirelessly. I'm looking for very basic functionality, like reading a few sensors, sending a couple of "AnalogWrite" commands to pins of my choosing and that's about it.

The most convenient way for me would be through a BT module (distance does not need to exceed 50 meters).

I'm hoping that people with more experience or that have done this before will be so kind as to let me know if there are any other easy plug&play ways to connect (wi-fi direct, through a web-service and web-module on the Arduino board...?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I have done this via a BlueTooth module like the [BlueTooth Mate Silver](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10393) or [BlueSMiRF](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10269) Silver from SparkFun.

This let's you setup a passthrough with the TX/RX.  On the Arduino side you just need to write a serial read/write application to handle the interaction.  You setup the modem at startup, open the serial channel and just wait for interaction.

On the Android side you can connect to the modem and send/receive commands.

On the other hand, if you look at the [IOIO](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10748) for Android, if you setup the correct host controller you should be able to talk over USB.  You can check out the Wiki and Schematics there to possibly tweak out how to do that.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to answer. Ioio looks really interesting! :D

Answer (score 2):

I think the fastest and cheapest way is Bluetooth Module from China's: HC-05, HC-06 and etc. It's 6-7$ per module. See work example: http://english.cxem.net/arduino/arduino4.php

Answer (score 1):

I have tried at least half a dozen ways to [connect Android and Arduino](http://sudarmuthu.com/blog/building-robots-using-arduino-and-android-at-droidcon). Out of all that Bluetooth seems to be the easiest one.

You could also try connecting them using wifi. But you need both of them to be in the same network and also you need a wifi shield for Arduino.